# Using TEXTJOIN to concatenate, then IF, INDEX, MATCH to fetch data - only works when the number of 'textjoined' cells is small

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, textjoin

I have data spread out on rows (SKU#s) that relate to a part# on the same row.  I have TEXTJOINED the SKU# cells into one cell on each row.  Then, on another sheet I have a formula that uses IF, INDEX and MATCH to look at a SKU# next to it, then search for that SKU# in the textjoined cell and return the part#.  It works well as long as there aren't too many SKU#s textjoined together.  12 SKU#s works fine, 30 does not.  I have as many as 80 SKU#s on a row.

I only know that one row of data that has 12 SKU#s works, but the rows with 30 or more SKU#s do not.  Unfortunately I don't have rows with say 15 or 20 so I can't determine exactly what the limit is.

I should note that all of the textjoined cells have data in them - none of them have thrown up an error.

The TEXTJOIN formula starting on row 5.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,H5:CI5)
```

The IF, INDEX & MATCH formula starting on row 5.

```
=IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("*"&A5&"*",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"")
```

What I need to have happen is for the formulas to work on up to 80 textjoined values (SKU#s).

Comment: How many matches at a time are you doing?  It can be done simpler with an array type formula but too many will cause issues with the recalc.

Comment: `=IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000)/('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000=A5),1)),"")`

Comment: On the sheet 'DEST MISMATCH' (it's essentially a pick list) I will most likely be copying and pasting a bunch of them at a time, the most would be all of the SKUs at once, which is 300-ish.  Because the 'DEST MISMATCH' sheet has conditional formatting to highlight duplicates (to see if I've picked each unit), scanning them one at a time is painfully slow.

Comment: Of course, I could remove the conditional formatting and do it at the end to avoid the slow data entry.  ;)

Comment: I tried your formula and it is mostly working except it's returning part#s in the row below the correct part#.

Comment: Are the references correct for that line?

Comment: As far as I can tell they are.  On row A5 I see A5 in the formula.  Otherwise everything else is static.  Same on other rows, say, A42 would show A42 in the formula.

Comment: Change `'DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000` to `'DEST MISMATCH'!$CO:$CO` sorry my bad.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for all your help.  I owe you a beer.  :)

Comment: I think you need to post your answer as an answer instead of a comment.  Then I can smack that check-mark and give you credit.  :)  The formula that worked was, =IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO:$CO,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000)/('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000=A5),1)),"")

Comment: Go ahead an self answer.  I am AFK, using phone.

Answer (score 0):

The formula that worked was,

```
=IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO:$CO,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000)/('DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CI$5000=A5),1)),"")
```

Credit to:  [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)